# C#: Convert ushort to float

Tags: c#, .net, casting

From a library I'm working with I recieve an array of `ushort`.

I want to convert them in an array of `float`: The first `ushort` represents the 16 MSB of the first `float` and the second `ushort` is the 16 LSB of the first `float`, and so on.

I tried with something like the following, but the value is cast as the value of the integer, not the raw bits:

```
ushort[] buffer = { 0xBF80, 0x0000 };
float f = (uint)buffer[0] << 16 | buffer[1];
// expected result  => f == -1            (0xBF800000)
// effective result => f == 3.21283686E+9 (0x4F3F8000)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at the [System.BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class.

In particular, the [ToSingle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle.aspx) method which takes a sequence of bytes and converts them to a float.

```
 ushort[] buffer = {0xBF80, 0x0000};
 byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
 bytes[0] = (byte)(buffer[1] & 0xFF);
 bytes[1] = (byte)(buffer[1] >> 8);
 bytes[2] = (byte)(buffer[0] & 0xFF);
 bytes[3] = (byte)(buffer[0] >> 8);
 float value = BitConverter.ToSingle( bytes, 0 );
```

**EDIT**
In the example, I had reversed the MSB/LSB order.. Now it is correct

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class for that.

Convert the two ushorts to byte arrays with [BitConverter.GetBytes(UInt16)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wwsdz3k.aspx), concatenate the two arrays and use [BitConverter.ToSingle(byte[] value,int startIndex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle.aspx) to convert the 4 bytes in the resulting array to a float.

Answer (score 1):

Use a C# union:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]    
public struct FloatUShortUnion {
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
    float floatValue;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
    ushort short1;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(16)]
    ushort short2;
}
```

Comment: The C# syntax for fixed-size arrays is `fixed ushort buffer[2];`, and I'm not sure if that works in conjunction with `[FieldOffset]`.
You can't use a normal C# array as that would convert the pointer to the array, not the array contents.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at the System.BitConverter class. You can use BitConverter.GetBytes to turn your ushorts into byte arrays, then combine your byte arrays and use BitConverter to turn the byte array into a float.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `System.BitConverter`, and convert the shorts to bytes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this threads super old but I had a similar problem nothing above fixed. I had to send a decimal value to a plc using modbus and my only option to write to the registers was a ushort array. Luckily the software on the plc could convert the ushort array back to the decimal, the issue was reading the data from the plc. Here is what I was able to get to work. ConvertTo takes the users input and creates the ushort array for the write and ConvertFrom takes the ushort array the program receives from the plc and converts it back to the float.

```
    private ushort[] ConvertTo(string value)
    {
        var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(float.Parse(value));
        return new ushort[] {
            BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, 0),
            BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, 2)
        };
    }

    private float ConvertFrom(ushort valueOne, ushort valueTwo)
    {
        byte[][] final = Array.ConvertAll(new ushort[] { valueOne, valueTwo }, delegate (ushort item) { return BitConverter.GetBytes(item); });
        return BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[4] { final[0][0], final[0][1], final[1][0], final[1][1] }, 0);
    }
```